# Idiom: quoted books

Tags: idioms

If there is, what idiom is used to refer to a book, which is famous and/or has interesting ideas, so that it's often quoted in speech, books etc.

Maybe something like "divided into quotations" ?

I'm not sure if there's an equiualent in English, but the following is an example of how it's used in Russian:

> «Маленький принц» переведён на 100
>   языков мира. Притча **разошлась на
>   цитаты**, самая известная из которых:
>   "Ты в ответе за тех, кого приручил".

Comment: Either there's no equivalent in English to the Russian phrase or I completely fail at English to be able to explain what I'm looking for.

Comment: What Russian phrase, exactly, do you have in mind?

Comment: @RegDwight: I've updated a question.

Comment: Thank you. I am not aware of a similar, let alone identical, construction in English.

Comment: @RegDwight: You're welcome. How do we treat this question, close, CW, something else?

Comment: I don't see a reason to close. CW would be justified if there were dozens of hard-to-pick-from options. As it stands, the question has a rather clear answer: there's no perfectly equivalent idiom in English, but there are certainly a couple expressions on which you can build to bring the same idea across. "The Little Prince is chock-full of memorable quotes", "The book gave birth to many winged words", or something to that extent is surely possible. Robusto's "oft-quoted" is not too far-fetched, either.

Comment: @RegDwight: Your examples are nice, as well. Thanks for assistance. I'll mark your comment as great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call it *oft-quoted* or *classic*. Often such a book will be called the "Bible" of a particular field of study.

> Adam Smith's *The Wealth of Nations* is considered by many to be the Bible of economics.

Comment: Close, but.. no :-[

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "[Take a leaf out of someone's book](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/take+a+leaf+out+of+someone%27s+book.html)" ?

> If you take a leaf out of someone's book, you copy something they do because it will help you.

Comment: Nope :-( That wouldn't say anything in regard to its practicality. It's used for talking about popular books, e. g. F. Nietzsche's [Thus Spoke Zarathustra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thus_Spoke_Zarathustra).

Comment: This expression is usually used figuratively, not referring to a literal book.  If I say that Christopher Hitchens took a leaf out of Richard Dawkins' book, I would mean that he was imitating some aspect of Dawkins' behaviour, not that he was quoting *The Selfish Gene*.

Comment: @PLL: Can I say "People take a leaf out of some book" ?